# Update field with another auto increment field value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL database with two fields:

1. Id (auto increment field).
2. Post_Id.

When I insert a new record both fields should have the same value. So I should update post_id with Id value, and at the same time make sure that I update the field with the right value not with any other new inserted record value.

I tried this SQL statement but it was very slow and I was not sure that I select the right value:

```
set @auto_id := (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name'
                  AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() ); 

update table_name set post_id= @auto_id where id=@auto_id ;
```

I don't have long experience with MySQL and I cannot change the table structure .

Comment: Is there a reason why you need two columns with the same value?  This sounds like a red flag/antipattern.

Comment: The design is just like that, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you followed is not transaction safe as well.

The best option I can think about is to use trigger

**Edit: According to @lagripe's mentionings**

```
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
AFTER INSERT ON sometable
BEGIN
  SET NEW.post_id := (SELECT id from sometable order by DESC limit 1) + 1 ; // you may need +1 here. I couldn't test it.
END
```

or you may consider to use `LAST_INSERT_ID`

```
insert into table_name values ( .... );
update table_name set post_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

but why do you need two columns with the same id at first place?

if you really need why don't you use computed/generated columns?

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  id DOUBLE,
  post_id DOUBLE as (id)
);
```

Comment: the AFTER condition don't allow changing in the new structure, even considering using BEFORE, the auto_incremented value don't exist (if so why would it be AI)..anyhow the trigger could be combined to get LIMIT 1 id by DESC

Comment: IF we use before, we dont have id yet. so  the best option is to use update command on trigger, but is it allowed ? let say `update sometable set post_id = new.id where id = new.id`

Comment: you didn't get my point, the id value will not be inserted so there is no new.id howsoever, otherwise it wouldn't be incrementation and there is no point in checking the AI option

Comment: I got your point now. Sorry lack of sleep I think. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use triggers :

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdatePOST_id
BEFORE INSERT ON table_db
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.post_id := (select id from table_db order by id DESC LIMIT 1)+1 ;
```

from now on, whatever you insert your as a value in post_id column will be replaced with the id inserted automatically.

Test :

```
    |id|post_id|
    |20|  20   |
    |21|  21   |
    |22|  22   |
    |23|  23   |
```

To drop the trigger :

```
DROP trigger UpdatePOST_id
```